# SQL SERVER: select data from other database with username and password

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases, ITG and PRO.

I need to pull data from PRO database and have to store it in ITG database. I wrote a query which works for local database tables, but I need it to be worked for different databases which has **username and password**

Query which I have been using -

```
insert into table3(column1,column2,column3,column4) 
 select column1,column2,column3,column4 
  from table2 a,table1 b 
  where a.table2=b.table1;
```

Comment: Use the appropriate "Connection String".

Comment: try to execute query in master DB.!
And post some data to let us check what are you doing and what is wrong with it.

Comment: If it's a different database on the same server simply prepend with the database name: `select column from database.schema.table`. If its on a different server you can create a linked server and use four part names but there are many gotchas and performance problems.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [LINKED SERVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Comment: Yes. I think so when I read the documents. @t-clausen.dk